# SQL Server : CASE to update based on entry in 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, case

I have 2 tables RDR1 and ORDR. I currently use the below `CASE` statement to update the column `UomCode` in the `RDR1` table:

Updated code below with the answer
         Update RDR1
          Set UomCode = (CASE

```
        WHEN LineStatus = 'C' and DelivrdQty = 0 THEN ''    
        WHEN LineStatus = 'C' and EncryptIV = NULL THEN 'DESPATCHED' 
        WHEN Quantity = DelivrdQty THEN 'DELIVERED'
        WHEN DelivrdQty = '0' THEN 'AWAITING STOCK'
        WHEN DelivrdQty < Quantity THEN 'PART SHIPPED'



    Else 'ERROR' End)

    from ORDR 
    inner join RDR1 
    On ORDR.DocEntry = RDR1.DocEntry
```

This works fine but I want to add a new line but that line requires a join but from reading examples online I cannot figure out where to put the join. The 2 tables join on a column called `DocEntry`

The statement will be

```
WHEN RDR1.LineStatus = 'C' AND ORDR.U_ActualDel = NULL
```

Can anyone point me to an example or let me know where to put the join please?

Comment: Use a `FROM` clause. `UPDATE R SET UomCode = ... FROM RDR1 R JOIN ORDR O ON...`

Comment: That is what I saw in the examples but I need to do it all in 1 statement, If I run it twice it overwrites the other options with NULL's, Im not sure how to nest both updates in 1 case statement.

Comment: Need to do "what" in one statement? That *is* one statement. Are you asking how to `UPDATE` both `RDR1` and `ORDR` in 1 statement? If so, the answer is "you can't"; a DML statement can only effect one object. If this doesn't help you, then provide consumable sample data and your expected results, so that we can help you.

Comment: The answer you seek begins here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry for the rubbish explanation. I am trying to add the join that you stated and update a single column by adding the join to my existing SQL I posted at the top.  I will give a better example, apologies its harder to write out than explain.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu I have edited my answser to reflect the changes I needed, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.